# Stack<> Pop error

Tags: c#, xna

im having trouble fixing this one error for a game

```
  if (type.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Dragon.BoundingRectangle))       
            {  
                rubys.Pop(i--);        
                OnTypeCollected(type.Dragon);  
            }
```

No overload for method 'Pop' takes 1 arguments

Comment: What should that mean `rubys.Pop(i--);`?

Comment: @I4V: it means that the ruby is removed from the stack!

Comment: what were you hoping the i-- in the pop was going to do ?

Comment: i-- would decrease the amount that rubys is
for example if ruby = 8, and i-- would decrease the value when the dragon intersects the ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to remove the ruby from the stack, and to see what ruby it is....

```
var rubyOnTopOfStack = rubys.Pop();
```

though you may want to :-

```
if(stack.Count > 0) rubys.Pop();
```

if there is any chance rubys will be empty otherwise it will throw an exception

Comment: It removes several rubies in this process when one is intersected by the dragon. I only want one ruby to disappear at a time. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @Peanues_are_delicous sounds like maybe you have the pop in the wrong place, if you have multiple conditions removing the ruby,  you might want to evaluate all conditions first, and set a flag to say remove a ruby, then pop the ruby last

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you you don't need to supply any arguments to `Pop`, and indeed the [documentation specifies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9say334k.aspx) that this method does not accept any arguments.

Try this:

```
if (type.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Dragon.BoundingRectangle))       
{  
    rubys.Pop();        
    OnTypeCollected(type.Dragon);  
}
```

Comment: Ive tried this, but when the Dragon intersects the ruby several rubies disappear not one.

Comment: @Peanues_are_delicous, What is your real question? since this answer is correct for question `No overload for method 'Pop' takes 1 arguments` . Use `Pop` without arguments :)

Comment: @Peanues_are_delicous It sounds like you may have radically misunderstood what `Pop` does. `Stack<T>` is a *data structure* it can help you in organizing code objects in your game but it doesn't refer to a 'stack' of gems on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
 rubys.Pop();
```